# Accord pour «chacun à votre/vos/ton tour»?

Tags: accord, syntaxe, possessif, morphologie

Si on présente des instructions (en tant qu'enseignant) pour une activité à un groupe d'élèves, et dans le groupe, chaque personne doit faire la même étape l'une après l'autre, quel accord faut-il si on utilise la phrase *chacun à son tour*?

1. Faites-le chacun à votre tour.
2. Faites-le chacun à vos tours.
3. Faites-le chacun à ton tour.

En fait, je ne suis pas tout à fait sûr de l'utilisation de *faites-le* au lieu de *fais-le*, mais mon idée est que ce premier a plus de sens.

(Ou peut-être qu'on se sert souvent de *à tour de rôle* dans ces situations pour éviter le besoin d'un accord?)

Answer (score 4):

Seule la formulation n° 1 est correcte.

- Faites-le chacun à votre tour.

On ne peut pas avoir *à ton tour* parce qu'on s'adresse à plus d'une personne. De même, la situation impliquant au moins deux personnes on ne peut pas avoir *fais-le*. Et *à vos tours* ne convient pas parce qu'on considère que chacun a un seul tour à la fois. Certains pourraient dire *faites-le chacun son tour*, même avec le verbe conjugué à la deuxième personne (*faites-le*) mais pour moi ça ne sonne pas bien.

À noter que le *à* est souvent omis, mais certains trouvent ça familier (voir [cette page](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/chacun-votre-tour-ou-chacun-a-votre-tour/)).

*À tour de rôle* convient parfaitement mais il n'y a aucune raison d'éviter *chacun (à) votre tour*.

---

Only #1 is correct.

- Faites-le chacun à votre tour.

You can't have *à ton tour* because you are addressing more than one person.
For the same reason you could not have *fais-le* since the situation implies more than one person.  And you can't have  *à vos tours* because we consider each has only one turn. Some  might say *Faites-le chacun son tour* even with the second person *faites-le* but it really sounds strange to me.

Note that *à* is often omitted but not everyone agrees on that, you can read about it [here](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/chacun-votre-tour-ou-chacun-a-votre-tour/).

*À tour de rôle* is absolutely fine but there's no reason to avoid *à votre tour*.

Comment: *Son* passerait mieux je pense dans *Allez ! Chacun son tour !*

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse. Après d'écrire le post, j'ai considéré «à son tour», aussi. J'imagine que ça marche au moins un peu avec n'importe quel destinataire? De plus, pourquoi pas «à ton tour» si c'est un prof parlant à des élèves?

Comment: @joshisanonymous On pourrait dire « faites le chacun (à) son tour », même si ne me plait pas à moi. Mais on ne peut pas avoir n'importe quel destinataire, « mon » ou « ton » ne marcherait pas si on a commence par « faites ». Par contre sans *faites* pas de problème : « à mon/ton/son tour » (à mon tour → *it's my turn*).